# how to change the format of print with regex or other possible way

Tags: java

Current Output

```
a [20],[4,20],[15],
as ,, ,,[16,17],
by , ,[16], , ,
```

I currently have the format above with square brackets and unnecessary commas 
So I want the below format to be printed and my code is here below

This the code that prints the above

But i want to modify the above code to format it without the brackets and colon with in each element with multiple numbers

```
EXPECTED out put

a  20, 4:20 ,15
as   ,  , 16:17
by   , 16 ,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own class say Log, implement the void print(Object) and friends to filter out the "[]". Then could use it as Log.print(list).
Or you could consider using something like:

```
("" + list).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
```

Which you probably should encapsulate in some sort of function such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    System.out.println("Non formatted: " + l);
    System.out.println(format0("" + l));
    System.out.println(format1("" + l));
    System.out.println(fmt(l)); // Short
}

static String format0(String s) {
    if(s.length() > 2)
        // Remove starting [ and ending ] from s
        return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    return s;
}

static String format1(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","");
}

static String fmt(Object o) { return format1(o.toString()); }
```

Cheers